Why is a question about sniffing/pulling/capturing data traveling through my network being marked as off-topic for a networking forum?

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: What is my AI camera uploading
I'm not asking to reverse engineer the camera or a computer... I'm trying to ask if there is a way to capture data that passes through my network from one internal IP to an external IP in a manner that is received similar to how it is sent (i.e. one file).  I know the concept of packet sniffers and data security, but it's not my fortay.  I thought a networking forum was the correct place to ask about getting information off of my network as it passes through.  If not a networking question - what is the right forum for this type of network security question?

As we know nothing about your network, the camera, or your abilities, we can't say if you can do anything. Is the camera wired or wireless? Do you have any wireless gear capable of monitor mode to capture any wireless traffic? Do you have any managed switches that support monitoring ("span")? Does your router support traffic capture? Can you run tcpdump on the camera itself? Do you even know how to capture traffic with tcpdump, wireshark, etc.? For most home networks, the answer is no to most or all of those. For an enterprise network, the answers should be yes.
Plucking the file out of the air as if it were being copied to you... that's a lot more difficult. If they use SSL/TLS, making any sense of what it's doing will be all but impossible.

That depends, and you need to provide much more information about the network. You have not provided any network information, such as a network design or drawing, the network device models, the network device configurations, etc.

I'd love to have the opportunity to provide more information.  I'm not an expert here - I can provide information, that's not an issue.  But, when the question is closed immediately and marked off-topic, it doesn't give me an opportunity to expand on it at all.  Should I be reposting the same question??

Remember that "Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment." Connecting a camera to a residential ISP cable modem does not count.

My commercial network may not be "professionally managed" enough for you... but to close questions based on your assumptions rather than to ask questions and understand the issue, reduces the overall benefit of sites like this.  This is not a home network.  You have no idea what my business is or how I use this camera.  Super frustrating when ignorance is what limits the validity of support forums!!

We would not need to assume if you provide the relevant details of your network. This is not a discussion forum, and we cannot speculate about an answer, we need the details. I have asked you for them, but you are withholding information that we need to answer the question.

If somebody is not an expert and is coming onto a help forum... they may not know the relevant details.  Perhaps being in control of a help based forum is not your strength.  Just something to take with you for future tickets.  Perhaps not everyone is as knowledgeable as you.  Patience and understanding go a long way in helping.  Then, others also get to learn and reference it later.  Just my 2 cents - perhaps I'm wrong and I've totally missed the point of this particular StackExchange.

If ther person does not know the relevant details, then we cannot help. It does explain that the network must be under your direct control, and if it is, then you should know the relevant details. Remember that this is for a "professionally managed network." If you are so in over your head on something that the question cannot be properly asked, then it is probably time to hire a consultant.

From the [tour]: This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
Just questions...
...and answers.
